# Remove rows with alphabets in a given column

Tags: python, pandas

Using the below codes to remove any null and na in a column 'sku'. The same column also has values as: 0001, 0002, etc.... and abc, def, etc... and how can I remove these rows that contain 'abc', 'def'?

```
    df= df[~df.sku.isnull()]
    df= df[~df.sku.isna()]
```

Comment: ```df = df[~df.sku.str.contains('abc',regex = True)]``` ?

Comment: dont have to be specific to 'abc' as there are others text objects in this column

Comment: Are you asking how to remove non-numeric values (such as `abc`, `a123`, `12k`)?

Comment: remove numeric values in any given column

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_numeric` with the coerce parameter, such that any non-numeric values will come back as null.  Check if those are null, and keep only those which are not.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'sku': ['abc','001']})

df.loc[~pd.to_numeric(df['sku'],errors='coerce').isnull()]
```

Or make sure it doesn't contain any alpha characters using regex.

```
df.loc[~df.sku.str.contains('[a-zA-Z]')]
```

Output

```
    sku
1   001
```